# Unreset GPIO Pins While System Resetting

Tags: stm32, keil

Is it possible to unreset some GPIO pins while using NVIC_SystemReset function at STM32 ?
Thanks in advance for your answers

Best Regards

I try to reach NVIC_SystemReset function. But not clear inside of this function.
Also this project is running on KEIL

Comment: it is not possible, I afraid

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is not possible, NVIC_SystemReset issues a general reset of all subsystems.

But probably, instead of system reset, you can just reset all peripheral expect one you need keep working, using *peripheral reset registers* in Reset and Clock Control module (RCC): `RCC_AHB1RSTR`, `RCC_AHB2RSTR`, `RCC_APB1RSTR`, `RCC_APB1RSTR`.

Example:

```
   // Issue reset of SPI2, SPI3, I2C1, I2C2, I2C3 on APB1 bus
   RCC->APB1RSTR = RCC_APB1RSTR_I2C3RST | RCC_APB1RSTR_I2C2RST | RCC_APB1RSTR_I2C1RST 
                 | RCC_APB1RSTR_SPI3RST | RCC_APB1RSTR_SPI2RST;
   __DMB(); // Data memory barrier
   RCC->APB1RSTR = 0; // deassert all reset signals
```

See detailed information in *RCC registers* description in Reference Manual for your MCU.

You may also need to disable all interrupts in NVIC:

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) NVIC->ICER[i] = 0xFFFFFFFFUL; // disable all interrupts 
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) NVIC->ICPR[i] = 0xFFFFFFFFUL; // clear all pending flags
```

if you want to restart the program, you can reload stack pointer to its top value, located at offset 0 of the flash memory and jump to the start address which is stored at offset 4. Note: flash memory is addressed starting from 0x08000000 address in the address space.

```
  uint32_t stack_top = *((volatile uint32_t*)FLASH_BASE);
  uint32_t entry_point = *((volatile uint32_t*)(FLASH_BASE + 4));

  __set_MSP(stack_top); // set stack top
  __ASM volatile ("BX %0" : : "r" (entry_point | 1) ); // jump to the entry point with bit 1 set
```